# Fix a corrupted text file

Tags: data-recovery, bluetooth, file-corruption

I had a plain English .txt file. After sending it via Bluetooth, the content is corrupted and has weird characters like : #šh‘÷ÔÈ

Any tips on what I can do to recover the original text?

Comment: -1  And you should not accept an answer when it has not answered your question. You don't have access to the file anymore so you can't test whether the answer worked for you or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text can be stored in different ways, the encoding of the text defines how the bytes of the file have to be interpreted by the text editor reading the file. For plain text files there is no way to store meta information about encoding, so the text editor picks its standard setting.

Under Windows most files are stored and read as [ANSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page), if you have a file that was stored as [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), with or without byte order mark (BOM), this will mess up the formating (vice versa). Additionally MacOS, Linux and Windows all use different styles of linebreaks, but these usually only mess with paragraphs and do not add funny characters.

I'd recommend getting a text editor like [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (for windows) which makes it easy to switch encoding.

Comment: Thanks. Already tried notepad++ with no luck. I've tried several encodings but none of them worked. I don't believe it's just an encoding problem. It looks like a damaged file for me. Any idea?

Comment: You could rule out a transmission problem by simply sending it again. But I think that bluetooth has some level of error correction, so the problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: The real problem is that I don't have access to the original file anymore. I +1 you but I'd appreciate any other ideas :) Thanks..

Comment: -1 Nothing you have said has anything to do with corruption of a file. And while the person that asked the question has accepted your answer, he admits he can't test whether or not it even answers his question.